# HTML Footer styling

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it would be possible to **move my footer** to the bottom of the page rather then display on the side like it is here [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRvSZ.png) essentially I want it to function like most other elements and always display below the element above it.

here is the code I used

```
<a href="Builders.html" style="color:#000000"><div style="border:3px solid black;width:800px;float:left;margin:5%"><center><h1>Builder</h1><br><p style="padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%">We are looking for someone who can offer their building skills and abilities to a passionate team.</p></center></div></a>

<a href="Programming.html" style="color:#000000"><div style="border:3px solid black;width:800px;float:left;margin:5%"><center><h1>Plugin Developer</h1><br><p style="padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%">Are you passionate about programming? Well if you are we would like your help on Plugin Development!.</p></center></div></a>

<!--End of body!-->

<footer>

   <style>
     .mar {
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
     }
   </style>

   <ul>     
      <li><a href="https://discord.gg/eTgnFHQ"><img src="Images/Discord.png" alt="Discord" height="35px" width="35px" class="mar"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/hoshko_studios/"><img src="Images/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram" height="35px" width="35px" class="mar"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCW_VW4njx6-d1jYDm2rlXoQ"><img src="Images/Youtube.png" alt="YouTube" height="35px" width="50px" class="mar"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/HoshkoStudios?s=09"><img src="Images/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" height="35px" width="35px" class="mar"></a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: You have only provided half of the code. Please include the entire HTML structure so we can help you resolve your problem. Also, please remove personal links from the code embed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this code.

```
<style>

 ul{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
 }

 li{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
 }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```